# Compare two lists for match but with different sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I searched for a whole time, but the only examples I find are 1:1 matches, but in my case I want something different:
First list:

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Second list:

`l2=[[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2],[1,2,3,4,5]]`

How do I search trough the second list until I find an exact match with the first one?

Comment: How is "exact match" different from "1:1 match"?

Comment: And how is this different from searching any other value in a list?

Comment: Does the order of the list in the second list as compared to the first one matter?

Comment: this is just `l1 in l2`.  python (unlike, say javascript) can do native equality matching on lists.